# Programatically switch stereo audio channels (left <> right) in headphones using C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, audio, naudio

### SCENARIO

For personal reasons I need to put my headphones in the opposite orientation, so what should be the left channel/headphone I put it in my right ear, and the right channel/headphone in the left ear.

When playing videogames this turns a big issue on games where the player must concentrate to find out where the sounds of the game come from (left or right audio channel) for example in a online shooter videogame, because... well, what comes from the left channel in-game I hear it on my right ear, and what comes from the right channel, on my left one. And here is where this question makes sense.

### QUESTION

How can I programatically switch the (stereo)audio channels of the master sound device/headphones (or the channels of a target executable) in Windows using C# or VB.NET?.

I have no problem in order to depend of **[NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)** or **[VistaCoreAudioApi](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=18520&av=112029)** libraries.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but have you tried putting your headphones on the opposite way?

Comment: @maccettura Hahaha good one. The problem is that the headphones are wireless and it produces lot of interferences if I put it on the right orientation. Buying a new headphones is not a solution, because it will produce the same interferences, so instead of that I just need to fix/switch the channel outputs in the system.

Comment: Have you tried moving the wireless source on the other side of your head and putting your headphones back on correctly?

Comment: @Ecnerwal yes, in front, back, left or right side no matter, it produces the intereferences only when I put the headphones in the normal orientation. Thankyou both for trying to solve this issue in a "natural" way, but I tried all what I can.

Comment: Haha sorry, it just sounds so weird, it is like your ears does not like what comes from the headphone. Reversing them could cause the same issue.

Comment: Assuming that this uses the 3.5mm audio jack, make your own "extension" core, but reverse the left and right leads. Alternatively, buy an extension cord, cut the wires and re-splice them.

Comment: http://tbeseda.tumblr.com/post/108592001234/windows-reverse-audio-channels

Comment: @Sam Axe Thankyou,  **Equalizer APO** worked perfectly!. However I'm a little bit dissapointed to register a shell extension only to swap the audio channels, the program its intrusive. I'll hold this question open for the interesting thing about how to do this using C# or VB.NET, maybe using **NAudio** lib.

Comment: NAudio would let you capture audio coming from other apps with `WasapiLoopbackCapture`, but not modify it. You need a virtual audio device driver to do low level stuff like that, so writing your own would be very difficult. The swapping channels part is easy - it's intercepting sound from other apps before it comes out the speakers that's not.

Comment: @Mark Heath Nice to hear a comment from the author of this awesome library!. At first I thought it might be as easy as enumerating my device using NAudio and then writting some tiny algorithm using the NAudio public members to swap channels; I never thought this was such a low-level operation because some popular games (like Unreal Tournament 2004) are capable to reverse stereo channels for its own executable in just one abstracted click in the options menu. Thanks for solving my doubts.

Answer (score -1):

The best way that I've found is to download and configure Equalizer APO as described in this post (should work for Windows 10 too): [how-do-i-reverse-audio-channels-win-windows-7](http://www.overclock.net/t/1114172/how-do-i-reverse-audio-channels-win-windows-7)